# How to create separate model(table) for Admin User and Normal User in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I just want separate table for **Normal User** and **Admin User**.

Comment: Why is this necessary? It would further complicate the authentication system, etc.

Comment: Just to ignore some unnecessary fields.
It is a requirement for my project.
Any work around?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Willem's comment, but you can try a few different patterns:

```
class BaseUser(AbstractBaseUser...):

    ''' base user class '''

    first_name = models.CharField(...)
    last_name = models.CharField(...)

    @property
    def is_normal_user(self):
        try:
            return self.normal_user and True
        except:
            return False

    @property
    def is_admin_user(self):
        try:
             return self.admin_user and True
        except:
             return False
    

class NormalUser(models.Model, ...):

    ''' normal user, extends BaseUser class '''

    base_user = models.OneToOneField('BaseUser', related_name='normal_user', ...)
    email = models.CharField(...)
        

class AdminUser(models.Model, ...):

    ''' admin user, extends BaseUser class '''

    base_user = models.OneToOneField('BaseUser', related_name='admin_user', ...)
    email = models.CharField(...)
```

Then you can something like this in your views:

```
user = BaseUser.objects.get(id=<the user id>)

if user.is_normal_user:
    
    # do something for normal users:

if user.is_admin_user:

    # do something for admin users:
```